# How to Return records between two values in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

friends, I know that my question is very basic but I am stuck with it as I am naive to SQL,So, apology for that.
I have table named TRANS_MONT and stores data like below

```
Year    month   amount  
2017     10     500  
2017     11     700  
2017     12     400  
2018     1      600  
2018     2      450  
2018     3      600
```

I am interested to return all those transaction from the year 2017 whose month value is greater than 10 and all those record from the year 2018 whose month value is less than 3 
I tried below query, but it does not work

```
Select * from TRANS_MONT where year in (2017, 2018) and month between 10 and 3
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: And the fastest guns in the west are out...

Comment: Hahahaha..  @AER

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
Select * from TRANS_MONT where (year=2017 and month>=10) OR (year=2018 and month<=3)
```

Comment: Will return, for example, also Apr.2017 while it shouldn't

Comment: @RobertKock, yes that's why I want to modify it

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn't pick up on the modular arithmetic of months if it is only stored as an integer.

Given it's really two logical statements, separate it with an `OR` to capture both situations in both years. Even if the month range was to work, it could technically also pick up the 12th month in 2018 for example.

```
SELECT * FROM TRANS_MONT
WHERE (Year = 2017 AND month > 10) OR (Year = 2018 AND month < 3)
```

Comment: Oct.2017 and Mar.2018 should be excluded

Answer (score 1):

It's quite straight forward:

```
SELECT *
FROM   trans_mont
WHERE  (year = 2017 AND month > 10)
   OR  (year = 2018 AND month < 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be something like this:

```
select * from Trans_Mont 
where (year=2017 and Month>10)
or (year=2018 and Month<3)
```

or

```
select * from Trans_Mont 
where (year * 100 + Month) BETWEEN 201710 and 201803
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state your DBMS, but with standard SQL you can do the following

```
select *
from trans_mont
where (year, month) between (2017,11) and (2018,2);
```

The `between` operator is inclusive of the edges, that's why the month on the lower end is 11 (not 10) and the month on the upper end is 2

Online example: https://rextester.com/VZPQ64850

Comment: Is there any other DBMS besides PostgreSQL supporting this?

Comment: @dnoeth: HSQLDB, H2, SQLite and if I'm not mistaken, DB2 as well

Comment: And Mimer SQL too.